# Strange Black-Brown Insect Identification

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

Interesting Insect from Singapore. Around 0.5cm. Has 2 tiny pinchers at its tail. Insect is black for most part.

Please zoom in on scotch tape:
[image]
[image]

Comment: That is an earwig. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [**earwig**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earwig), an [insect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insect) in the order [Dermaptera](https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/course/ent425/library/compendium/dermaptera.html) that has notably robust [cerci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cercus).

[image]

<sup>Credit: [Ron Yeo](http://tidechaser.blogspot.com/2013/06/insects-insecta-singapore.html)</sup>

Note that the name comes from an old wives' tale about these insects crawling into people's ears. [They don't](https://www3.extension.umn.edu/local/rice/county-agriculture-educator/article/information-about-earwigs-and-how-manage-them):

> Earwigs do get their name from the belief that they climb into human ears while individuals are asleep, however, **this belief is fortunately untrue**

Based on the sexing rules indicated [here](https://projects.ncsu.edu/cals/course/ent425/library/compendium/dermaptera.html), your specimen's relatively straight cerci might be an indication that you found a female.

Earwigs are found worldwide, and with about 2000 species ([source](https://mapress.com/zootaxa/2011/f/zt03148p103.pdf)), it'll be difficult to narrow this down to species. If you can get access to a local [dichotomous key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-access_key) or other accurate insect ID guide, you might be able to narrow further.